# Anthill build giving errors in OnSite machine

Tags: build, anthill

We did a build of our app locally. It went smoothly without errors. But the build using anthill on onsite machine is giving errors like "cannot find symbol" in the class file generated. We downloaded the whole app in another machine here locally and the build was again went good. Want to know what may be possible issue?

The methods are already imported in the class files so there is no way of getting these errors. Also the jar file having these class files is downloaded for compiling from the repository.. The versions are same locally and onsite.

The only difference I found through log files is jdk 1.5.0 and 1.5.0_17.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually running the build on the machine AntHill is building it on? Make sure you do it as the use AntHill is running as.